# Stripe card fields not showing properly in live-mode

Tags: python-3.x, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

When using the test keys everything works fine, but when entering the live keys the fields are not shown correctly in heroku server,
In localhost it is working fine for both test and live keys.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Can you show some code snippets of how it works? its a bit hard to understand why it happens to you with the image only

Comment: Also any error output of the browser console would be helpful.

Comment: As mentioned, look at the browser console. 99% of the time this is because you're not hosting the page on `https`, which is _required_ when accepting a payment in livemode using stripe.js and there's an error/warning printed to the console saying as much.